# Why can't GHC solve this unification using the instance constraint?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

### Background

Consider this program:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BlockArguments, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, Rank2Types, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Functor.Identity

data Mu a
  = Mu (forall f x y. (Fun a x y, Applicative f) => f x -> f (Mu y))

class Fun t x y where
  runF :: t -> x -> Mu y

instance (a ~ x, b ~ y) => Fun (a -> b) x y where
  runF f x = yield (f x)

instance (Fun k x y) => Fun (Mu k) x y where
  runF (Mu f) x = runIdentity (f (Identity x))

yield :: a -> Mu a
yield a = Mu \x -> (runF a) <$> x
```

This is a kind of encoding of continued computation, that you can repeatedly pass (side-effecting) arguments to. The use of `Fun` is because I want to treat a `Mu (Mu a)` like a `Mu a` - you can repeatedly pass arguments to both, a `Mu (Mu a)` just passes arguments to the inner `Mu a`.

### The problem

I now want to define

```hs
debind :: (a -> Mu b) -> Mu (a -> b)
debind f = Mu \fa -> f <$> fa
```

The trouble is that this doesn't compile - `fa` actually has the type `f x` for the quantified `x` in the data constructor of `Mu`, instead of `f a`, and the return type of `f <$> fa` needs to be `f (Mu y)`, not `f (Mu b)`.

But `Fun (a -> b) x y` only has one possible instance for quantified `a`,`b`,`x`,`y` - namely, the one I specified. GHC *should* be able to use that instance, and its constraint, to unify `a ~ x` and `b ~ y` - so why doesn't it?

Comment: What is `yield` above?

Comment: Ah, I mistakenly cut `yield` because I thought it was irrelevant to the example. It is the lifter `a -> Mu a` - I'll add it in.

Answer (score 2):

Changing your class to use type families to express the dependencies, I was able to make this compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, Rank2Types, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Functor.Identity

data Mu a
  = Mu (forall f. (Fun a, Applicative f) => f (Dom a) -> f (Mu (Cod a)))

class Fun t where
  type Dom t
  type Cod t
  runF :: t -> Dom t -> Mu (Cod t)

instance Fun (a -> b) where
  type Dom (a->b) = a
  type Cod (a->b) = b
  runF f x = yield (f x)

instance Fun k => Fun (Mu k) where
  type Dom (Mu k) = Dom k
  type Cod (Mu k) = Cod k
  runF (Mu f) x = runIdentity (f (Identity x))

yield :: a -> Mu a
yield a = Mu (\x -> runF a <$> x)

debind :: (a -> Mu b) -> Mu (a -> b)
debind f = Mu (\fa -> f <$> fa)
```

For some reason, I was unable to make it work with functional dependencies.

Anyway, you should be able to see what's going on. Now, `Fun` only takes the first argument `t`, while the second and third one are replaced by type families `Dom t` and `Cod t` representing the domain and codomain of the function-like type `t`. This also allows to remove the `forall x y` part inside the definition of `Mu`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this alternative, thanks! I don't think functional dependencies should make any difference to the GHC instance selection process - since it doesn't change the set of relevant possible instances.

If nobody can solve the instance problem, I'll accept this.

Comment: I'll add that this solves the example I gave, but unfortunately does not work for the more general case I'm looking for (where the second instance is `(Fun k) => Fun (f k)` with some constraint on `f`) since instance constraints are not considered for associated type family overlap - so it's impossible to declare an instance for `(->) a b` *and* `f k`, just in case `(->) a ~ f` and `b ~ k`.